# Why do we need a ListIterator?

Tags: linked-list, java

Was reading up on the API of `ListIterator` which provides a lot of functions to navigate/edit a linkedlist. But my question is why do we need a `ListIterator` to navigate forwards and backwards through the list if we can use the `get()` method to index elements.

Comment: Accessing elements of a linked list by index is an `O(n)` operation. At a guess the `ListIterator` most likely resolves this by being aware that you are performing simple iteration and so can make fetching the next node `O(1)` time.

Comment: @CollinD Thanks for the response. I did not think of the computational complexity. Well said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason you need an `Iterator`, plus its extra API. The iterator knows the best way to advance and retreat over the list. Better in this case than you do. `List.get(int index)` is *O(N)* on a linked list; chasing the links is *O(1)*.